# Android Permission Denial - App crashes on FutureTask

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've got an app that needs to ask for permission to read contacts from an Android device. I'm aware of that I need to check for permission...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
} else {
     loadContacts();
}
```

My problem is that if the **user denies access** my app is crashing

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: xxxxxxxxx, PID: 10376
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{3ad4917 10376:xxxxxxxxx/u0a196} (pid=10376, uid=10196) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4241)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6392)
      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2321)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1521)
      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:486)
      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**I understand that I don't have access**, but surely the app shouldn't crash, it should just mean I can't read the contacts? It seems to be talking about a `FutureTask` which I'm not sure what this is? I've tried commenting out all the code that actually does the contact access and it still crashes before it gets anywhere near trying to read the contacts. I just want to handle this situation gracefully and I don't appear to be getting the chance?

The Manifest has the permission set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Also if I go into Application Manager and change the settings for the app so that the app does have access to contacts the app runs fine, and I've still not accessed the contacts yet, this is purely on start up

Comment: The function checkSelfPermission must have the context as parameter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.htm). You can find example here : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Guillaume - thanks for the suggestion, I applied that change, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Flexicoder Looking at your log there is no question that your app is crashing because it is going ahead with the read even after the permission is revoked.

 You can see by the `SecurityException` that it is trying to read from `ContactsProvider2` 

You haven't provided the full code so it is more difficult, but you should verify how you end up in a "codepath" that - triggers the loadInBackground method of the `CursorLoader` 

> at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)


From the log it definitely seems like that is what is happening

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueMSI'll investigate, I didn't think I was doing anything like that, but at least its something to go on

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `ActivityCompat`, which supports it better

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    } else {
        loadContacts();
    }
```

Comment: The thing is its not even getting to my checkpermission code now without crashing - because I've denied access its not letting me go any further